# Does an additional resolver in AppSync/ DynamoDB bill twice for read operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I need to query after my users favorite posts. With this query they should be able to see the post with his information like title and likes. Considering that the value of some attributes like ***total likes*** can change over time, I can't add these values into the *favorite* dataset. If I would do that, I had to update every favorite dataset when someone likes a post to keep them up to date.
This lead me to the decision that I don't add these informations (for example total likes) into a favorite entry and just attach an additional resolver for the post attribute. It could look like this:

```
type Post {
  pid: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  likes: Int      // <-- An attribute which I need to show while displaying favorites
}

type Favorite{
  fid: ID!
  pid: String!
  ...
  post: Post!  // <-- This has an own resolver
}
```

The attribute *Post* has his own additional resolver attached through AWS AppSync which could look like this

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.source.pid),
     }
 }
```

If a user would query his own favorites, would this cost twice of the read operation ? Since it needs two ***GetItem*** Operation for each in the result 

Example:
     Query favorites with limit 10 would cost 20 read ops (10 for plain Favorite data (fid and pid) and 10 for post data through the additional resolver.

Or does DynamoDB bundle it up into one read operation in the background ? 
**Furthermore** is this an acceptable solution (or a normal approach) for this problem ? Are you using this technique ? Or would this get very expensive while scaling ? 

**EDIT**: Im using only one table, so every dataset is in it.

Comment: To query the list of favorites, are you using a DynamoDB Query? If yes then the cost would be 1 Query + N * 1 GetItem to retrieve the post for each favorite. 
You said "If I would do that, I had to update every favorite dataset when someone likes a post to keep them up to date." -> why don't you refresh the likes only when post is accessed rather than when it's updated.

Comment: @Tinou That would be expensive since updates are write operations, isn't it ? So I would need a write op every item I query my favorites. Can you explain 1 Query + N* 1 GetItem ? If I query 10 favorites, would it be 11 ? And yes I'm using a DynamoDB Query for that which is getting called from an Android device. getFavorites() is defined in the query block in my schema. Thank you for your help :)